# How can I avoid Dimension exception using method convertToImage() on class PDPage when converting to TIF

Tags: java, exception, pdfbox, dimension

I have around 500 PDF documents which I need converted into TIF files. I am using PDDocument and PDPage from Apache PDFBox 1.8.2 API. The code is working on almost all PDF documents except around 20 where I get the exception:

> jun 14, 2013 8:08:09 AM
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap getRGBImage
>   SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dimensions (width=1000000
>   height=1000000) are too large java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Dimensions (width=1000000 height=1000000) are too large   at
>   java.awt.image.SampleModel.(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.awt.image.PixelInterleavedSampleModel.(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KRenderedImageCodecLib.createSampleModel(J2KRenderedImageCodecLib.java:741)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KRenderedImageCodecLib.createOriginalSampleModel(J2KRenderedImageCodecLib.java:729)
>     at
>   com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KRenderedImageCodecLib.(J2KRenderedImageCodecLib.java:261)     at
>   com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg2000.J2KImageReaderCodecLib.read(J2KImageReaderCodecLib.java:364)
>     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.filter.JPXFilter.decode(JPXFilter.java:53)  at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.doDecode(COSStream.java:295)  at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.doDecode(COSStream.java:237)  at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSStream.getUnfilteredStream(COSStream.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.createInputStream(PDStream.java:231)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.getByteArray(PDStream.java:509)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.xobject.PDPixelMap.getRGBImage(PDPixelMap.java:185)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.pagedrawer.Invoke.process(Invoke.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:554)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:268)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processSubStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:125)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:781)
>     at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.convertToImage(PDPage.java:712)
>     at dk.atkins.sa.creator.CreateTIFF.pdf(CreateTIFF.java:142)     at
>   dk.atkins.sa.creator.DocumentIndex.build(DocumentIndex.java:288)  at
>   dk.atkins.sa.creator.DocumentIndex.run(DocumentIndex.java:204)
>
> jun 14, 2013 8:08:09 AM
>   org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.pagedrawer.Invoke process WARNING:
>   getRGBImage returned NULL

What can I do to avoid this exception? Should I use an alternative PDF converter? The exception is thrown when calling method `convertToImage()`.

```
List<PDPage> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
    ImageOutputStream ios = null;
    try {
        PDPage page = pages.get(i);
        BufferedImage thisImage = page.convertToImage();
        ...
```

**Complain:** The exception is thrown inside the PDFBox API and catched inside the PDFBox API so I do not have a chance to highlight any problem.

Comment: Does it help to specify the type and resolution? eg `page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR, 200)` or `page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, 600);` A terapixel image (1000000 x 1000000) does seem excessive.

Comment: I have tried that and it makes different. When I open the PDF document with PDFReader it looks like an ordinary PDF from a scanner. I have tried to use Aspose toolkit also, Aspose just makes white pages out of the PDF document.

Comment: This line page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR, 200) is giving the same error. The second line page.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY, 600); is givings SEVERE: Something went wrong ... the pixelmap doesn't contain any data.
jun 25, 2013 3:17:03 PM org.apache.pdfbox.util.operator.pagedrawer.Invoke process